# replace char with line break

Tags: php, str-replace

I have tried several solutions to replace a `,` with aeither `<br />` or `\n\r`

To no avail I am left stuck and wondering if the wonderful users of SO could lend a hand.

```
$row['address'] = 'Unit A, 64 Alert Square, London, E16';

echo "Address: ". nl2br(str_replace(',',' \r\n ', $row['address']));
```

result: `Unit A \r\n 64 \r\n Alert \r\n Square \r\n London \r\n E16`

needed, well, desired effect:

```
Unit A
64 Alert Square
London
E16
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Character escapes like `\r` and `\n` need to be double quotes or heredocs to be understood by PHP, e.g.:

`echo "Address: ". nl2br(str_replace(',', "\n", $row['address']));`

Comment: In my case when trying to do the same thing, adding a "\n" didn't work for some reason. So as an alternative I was forced to use "<br>".